# Output number of occurrences of id in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
PK     Date      ID
=== =========== ===    
1   07/04/2017   22
2   07/05/2017   22  
3   07/07/2017   03    
4   07/08/2017   04     
5   07/09/2017   22    
6   07/09/2017   22    
7   07/10/2017   05
8   07/11/2017   03    
9   07/11/2017   03    
10  07/11/2017   03
```

I want to count the number of ID occurred in a given week/month, something like this.

```
ID  Count
22    3   --> count as 1 only in the same date occurred twice one 07/09/2017
03    2   --> same as above, increment only one regardless how many times it occurred in a same date
04    1
05    1
```

I'm trying to implement this in a perl file, to output/print it in a csv file, I have no idea on what query will I execute.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow is probably not the best place for your question.

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`.

Comment: i have tried select id, date, count(ID) count from table where date between '07-04-2017' and '07-11-2017' group by id, date order by id
and this will only shows  total occurrences of every id, for example 10x occurred this day

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple case of count distinct and group by:

```
SELECT Id, COUNT(DISTINCT [Date]) As [Count]
FROM TableName
WHERE [Date] >= @StartDate
AND [Date] <= @EndDate
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY [Count] DESC
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT` with `DISTINCT` e.g.:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(DISTINCT Date) 
FROM table
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more abot how to get month from a date in [get month from a date](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp) (it also works for year).

Your query will be :

```
select DATEPART(mm,Date) AS month, COUNT(ID) AS count from table group by month
```

Hope that helped you.